# Needing to link to some c++ standard library headers from rust

Tags: c++, rust

I am building an FFI crate (the sys crate part specifically), and for the most part it's a c library with a single cpp file in it. Looks like it's some sort of vendor file.

svm.cpp links to the following standard library headers

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
```

Strangely, this cpp file doesn't seem to link to the c++ standard libraries that it depends on, so I had to do it through the rust build system.

previously I was able to get this working by adding the following line to my build.rs

```rs
println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=stdc++");
```

This works on linux using the gnu toolchain, but i'm trying to get this to work on windows using the msvc toolchain.
So the problem is that stdc++ isn't a standardized header, and isn't included in msvc. How can I link directly to each of these c++ standard library headers instead of using stdc++?

I already tried the naive approach of just trying to link to math like so

```rs
println!("cargo:rustc-flags=-l dylib=math");
```

which did not yield any results

Comment: I pretty sure header are totally useless, you just want to link to c++ standard library and I have no idea how you do it in Rust. However, your request is weird. No one should need to do that expect crate that expose safe interface to c++ crate and so it's look to me you have an xy problem

Comment: I'm not trying to expose the c++ standard library through a rust crate, the library I'm trying to wrap depends on a singular cpp file that links to a bunch of c++ stdlib stuff. I'm not creating any bindgens for the c++stdlib. Inexplicably, this vendor cpp file in this c library doesn't seem to want to link to these standard libraries, so I had to do it using linker flags in my build script. This is fine on linux with the gnu toolchain, but doesn't work on windows with msvc as stdc++ isn't standard